# COSMOS DB Trigger Azure Function changefeed error

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions-core-tools

I am using azure function 1.0.13 SDK with 1.2.0 DocumentDB extension. The following is the code that i am trying to run:

```
  [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "database",
            collectionName: "collection",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "DBConn",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases")]IReadOnlyList<Document> documents, TraceWriter log)
        {
            if (documents != null && documents.Count > 0)
            {
                log.Verbose("Documents modified " + documents.Count);
                log.Verbose("First document Id " + documents[0].Id);
            }
        }
```

Now when I try debugging locally in VS, I get the following error:

Function1: The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB: Either the source collection 'database' (in database 'database')  or the lease collection 'leases' (in database 'database') does not exist. Both collections must exist before the listener starts. To automatically create the lease collection, set 'CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists' to 'true'. Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client: Message: {"Errors":["Resource Not Found"]}

[6/26/2018 3:24:49 PM] ActivityId: 7738cc1a-f8f6-45a2-a3c6-73d342a8d4c3, Request URI: /apps/4c8d65d7-216b-46b4-abb7-52c1a0c7123f/services/b3a1db8d-b82c-403e-8d89-9709b5068482/partitions/0a2bdc5c-471b-4acc-a093-6332c8ce1d5d/replicas/131727365611181690s, RequestStats:
[6/26/2018 3:24:49 PM] ResponseTime: 2018-06-26T15:24:48.5014600Z, StoreReadResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://10.98.106.50:11000/apps/4c8d65d7-216b-46b4-abb7-52c1a0c7123f/services/b3a1db8d-b82c-403e-8d89-9709b5068482/partitions/0a2bdc5c-471b-4acc-a093-6332c8ce1d5d/replicas/131727365611181690s, LSN: 125, GlobalCommittedLsn: 125, PartitionKeyRangeId: , IsValid: True, StatusCode: 0, IsGone: False, IsNotFound: True, IsInvalidPartition: False, RequestCharge: 1, ItemLSN: -1, ResourceType: Collection, OperationType: Read
[6/26/2018 3:24:49 PM] ResponseTime: 2018-06-26T15:24:48.5014600Z, StoreReadResult: StorePhysicalAddress: rntbd://10.98.108.179:11000/apps/4c8d65d7-216b-46b4-abb7-52c1a0c7123f/services/b3a1db8d-b82c-403e-8d89-9709b5068482/partitions/0a2bdc5c-471b-4acc-a093-6332c8ce1d5d/replicas/131727455073557671s, LSN: 125, GlobalCommittedLsn: 125, PartitionKeyRangeId: , IsValid: True, StatusCode: 0, IsGone: False, IsNotFound: True, IsInvalidPartition: False, RequestCharge: 1, ItemLSN: -1, ResourceType: Collection, OperationType: Read
[6/26/2018 3:24:49 PM] , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.0.0.0.

I have copied and pasted the entire primary connection string from azure portal. I have checked multiple times to make sure that the database and collection names are found.

"database" and "collection" were modified for security reason.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

For the function trigger to work it needs to create a collection called leases. You can do this your self, or update the CosmosDBTrigger trigger to tell the function host it can make it if it doesn't exist

`[CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "database",
            collectionName: "collection",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "DBConn",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases",
            CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true)]`

You can see here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb#trigger---c-example

Comment: Thank you for the response. I can see the documentation shows to add that option. When I create a new function from the template however that option is not included by default.

Comment: thats because it adds a cost. Microsoft can't just say it will add a collection without you being explicit that you want it.

Comment: Thank you. However after applying the changes I am now receiving the following strange error messages:

Error writing logs to table storage: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'test.table.core.windows.net' ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'test.table.core.windows.net'
[
['test.table.core.windows.net'. System: The remote name could not be resolved: 'test.table.core.windows.net'.
"Test" is used in lieu of the actual URL. I have created a blank Storage service with premium option.

Comment: It sounds like your connection string is wrong. Does your connection string have the connectino key in it?

Comment: Yes it does. And i can see that it is working by responding to events when inserting and modifying records but seems to do nothing to the storage.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is explained in the error you are seeing:

> Function1: The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DocumentDB: Either the source
>   collection 'database' (in database 'database') or the lease collection
>   'leases' (in database 'database') does not exist. Both collections
>   must exist before the listener starts. To automatically create the
>   lease collection, set 'CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists' to 'true'.
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client: Message: {"Errors":["Resource Not
>   Found"]}

Both collections need to exist, the collection called `database` in your case and the leases collection called `leases`. As the message says, you can use `CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists` to automatically create the leases collection, but the source collection needs to exists.

If you want to understand the reason behind the need of the leases collection, you can read it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#understand-cf). In short, as the Function reads the [Change Feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed), it needs to checkpoint its progress in order to be resilient to any restart/stop in a separate collection. This collection can be in the same Account or you can customize its account and database.

Comment: Thank you. Yes you are correct. However that has led to the problem as commented above.

Comment: I see. That is unrelated to the Cosmos DB Trigger. It seems like there is an issue connecting to your Storage account. Azure Functions requires a Storage Account with Tables available to write logs to, as the error message you shared explains. Please make sure your Storage Account has the Tables service available and that your Connection String is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the Cosmos DB connection string. Try opening the same via [Cosmos DB Explorer](https://cosmos.azure.com/)